# Trouble accessing dictionary with dot notation in Django Template

Tags: django

I am having trouble with using the template language dot notation to access values in my dictionary.

Here is an example of what one of my dictionary's could look like:

```
{2L: {'dob': datetime.date(2012, 7, 7), 'image': u'', 'user_id': 3L, 'id': 2L, 'email': u'blank@blank.com'}, 3L: {'dob': datetime.date(2012, 7, 7), 'image': u'', 'user_id': 4L, 'id': 3L, 'email': u'blank@blank.com'}}
```

The way I would access this in Python is like so:

```
D[2]['email']
```

Here is what I've tried in my template:

```
{% for d in D %}
    {% if d == a.user_id %} {{ D.d.email }} {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

It is not printing out anything... (I have tested that my boolean evaluates to True, by adding some HTML inside the execution block.

Can you help me with the notation here? I know its this: `{{ D.d.email }}` that is wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't want `{{ D.d.email }}`, that looks up D['d'].  There is no syntax in Django templates to use a variable as a key.

Use this:

```
{% for d,v in D.items %}
    {% if d == a.user_id %} {{ v.email }} {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```